# AutoMapping Custom Collections with FluentNHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, collections, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

I am retrofitting a very large application to use NHibernate as it's data access strategy. Everything is going well with AutoMapping. Luckily when the domain layer was built, we used a code generator.  The main issue that I am running into now is that every collection is hidden behind a custom class that derives from List<>. For example

```
public class League
{
   public OwnerList owners {get;set;}
}
public class OwnerList : AppList<Owner>  { }
public class AppList<T> : List<T>  { }
```

What kind of Convention do I have to write to get this done?

Comment: "Luckily when the domain layer was built, we used a code generator" - I fail to see how that would be a good thing. Exposing concrete list types is a big design mistake.

Comment: It's a good thing that there was uniformity between the domain and the database, so a direct domain mapping is easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're going to be able to achieve this with a convention. You will have to create an auto mapping override and then do the following:

```
mapping.HasMany(l => a.owners).CollectionType<OwnerList>();
```

Comment: This isn't a good solution, but it's the only one that works.