# Cast an ICollection in order to override GetOrphans()

Tags: c#, nhibernate, casting

I would like to allow reparenting in Fluent NHibernate.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5623693/1394336) I read that I have to create two classes which inherit from `IUserCollectionType` and `PersistentGenericBag<MyClass>`. If I change `Box` from the example to my own classname, everything works fine - except one thing: In the class which inherits from `PersistentGenericBag<MyClass>` I can't override `GetOrphans()` because `Cast()` is not defined for an `ICollection`.
This is what I would like to have:

```
public override ICollection GetOrphans(object snapshot, string entityName)
{
    var orphans = base.GetOrphans(snapshot, entityName)
        .Cast<MyCalss>()
        .Where(b => ReferenceEquals(null, b.CurrentStorage))
        .ToArray();

    return orphans;
}
```

How can I use `Cast` on an `ICollection`?

**Edit**
This is the exact error I get (unfortunatly it's german): `Fehler   1   "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>" enthält keine Definition für "Cast", und es konnte keine Erweiterungsmethode "Cast" gefunden werden, die ein erstes Argument vom Typ "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>" akzeptiert. (Fehlt eine Using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis?)`

Comment: Do you have the necessary `using System.Linq;` in your file? What is the exact error message what you get?

Comment: Thank you! Now it works! I thought Visual Studio would tell me if I have to add an using directive, but it didn't. I added `using System.Linq;` an now I'm able to access `Cast()`
Could you please post your hint as an answer? Than I could accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Cast<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) living in the `System.Linq` namespace.

And to use an extension method you need to add it's namespace with an `using` directive.

So just add the following `using` to your file and it should work:

```
using System.Linq;
```